# Ubuntu 16.04 only recognizes 24GB RAM out of 32GB

Tags: hardware, ram

I recently purchased a new Desktop PC with 4x8 GB RAM. However, the operating system (Ubuntu 16.04, 64 bit) only reports 24 GB RAM instead of 32. I already checked the sticks physically, they are installed correctly.

I am aware that the OS might occupy some of the memory, but as 8 GB of missing RAM seems excessive and 3x8 equals 24 I figured I should ask people that have more experience than me. Some of the tools give me conflicting information (as described below) -- I am not sure what is going on and I couldn't find anything that solves my problem, so I'm posting here.

Let me start with the **relevant hardware**:

- Mainboard: Asrock 970M Pro3 970 (supports up to 64 GB)
- RAM: G.Skill D332GB 1600-999 RipjawsX K4 GSK, 4x8 GB
- GPU: Asus 4GB D5 GTX 1050 TI PH (I read somewhere that the GPU occupies some of the RAM, not sure if that is important here...)

**What I have tried already:**

This is where it gets interesting...

- The BIOS reports all 4 RAM sticks correctly
- `sudo dmidecode --type memory` also detects all 4 sticks
- `sudo lshw -class memory` shows 32GB RAM too

However...

- "About this computer" reports 23.5 GiB
- `htop` also reports 23.5G
- `cat /proc/meminfo` outputs 24660520 kB
- `free -m` sees 24082 MB RAM
- running memtest only tested 24 GB of RAM (and found no errors)

Can anybody explain what is going on? Is this expected behaviour or is there something wrong?

Here is the full **output of the commands** mentioned above:

*sudo dmidecode --type memory*

```
# dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000D
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: A1_DIMM0
    Bank Locator: A1_BANK0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Undefined       
    Serial Number: 00000000  
    Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum0
    Part Number: F3-1600C9-8GXM    
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 667 MHz

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000D
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: A1_DIMM1
    Bank Locator: A1_BANK1
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Undefined       
    Serial Number: 00000000  
    Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum1
    Part Number: F3-1600C9-8GXM    
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 667 MHz

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000D
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: A1_DIMM2
    Bank Locator: A1_BANK2
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Undefined       
    Serial Number: 00000000  
    Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum2
    Part Number: F3-1600C9-8GXM    
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 667 MHz

Handle 0x0015, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000D
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: A1_DIMM3
    Bank Locator: A1_BANK3
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Undefined       
    Serial Number: 00000000  
    Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum3
    Part Number: F3-1600C9-8GXM    
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 667 MHz
```

*sudo lshw -class memory*

```
  *-firmware              
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: P1.60
       date: 06/17/2016
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 4032KiB
   capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial     int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1-Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L2-Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L3-Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: d
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 32GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
          product: F3-1600C9-8GXM
          vendor: Undefined
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: A1_DIMM0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
          product: F3-1600C9-8GXM
          vendor: Undefined
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: A1_DIMM1
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
          product: F3-1600C9-8GXM
          vendor: Undefined
          physical id: 2
          serial: 00000000
          slot: A1_DIMM2
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
          product: F3-1600C9-8GXM
          vendor: Undefined
          physical id: 3
          serial: 00000000
          slot: A1_DIMM3
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
```

*cat /proc/meminfo*

```
MemTotal:       24660520 kB
MemFree:        21122376 kB
MemAvailable:   21926440 kB
Buffers:          140544 kB
Cached:           963872 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          2574684 kB
Inactive:         554432 kB
Active(anon):    2027416 kB
Inactive(anon):    71840 kB
Active(file):     547268 kB
Inactive(file):   482592 kB
Unevictable:          48 kB
Mlocked:              48 kB
SwapTotal:      25137148 kB
SwapFree:       25137148 kB
Dirty:                72 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       2024884 kB
Mapped:           426756 kB
Shmem:             74552 kB
Slab:             170052 kB
SReclaimable:     120684 kB
SUnreclaim:        49368 kB
KernelStack:       11760 kB
PageTables:        48856 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    37467408 kB
Committed_AS:    8069992 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    397312 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      277632 kB
DirectMap2M:     7032832 kB
DirectMap1G:    19922944 kB
```

*free -m*

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache        available
Mem:          24082        2263       20553          68        1264       21364
Swap:         24547           0       24547
```

Comment: some processors have a max mem

Comment: Interesting, haven't heard of that before... The CPU is an AMD FX-8350, but all I can find for that is something about a limit on the RAM frequency, not the amount of RAM.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_limit#CPU_addressing_limits in my last laptop i had an intel i3 M370 which had a ram limit of 8G according to the intel website. (Much smaller than the size stated for 36bit on wikipedia)

Comment: https://ark.intel.com/products/49020/Intel-Core-i3-370M-Processor-3M-cache-2_40-GHz

Comment: i'm pretty sure an AMD FX-8350 would have a pretty big limit though...

Comment: run a memtest (you will find it in the boot loader)

Comment: @SebastianHofer what microprocessor do you use?

Comment: @mikejonesey yes i was about to suggest this. exactly 8GB is missing - the size of one RAM stick

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the CPU would have a problem with 32GB either. As stated above, I already ran memtest and it only detected/tested 24GB.

Comment: I just tried running memtest again, and I noticed that you can actually see the problem there. All 4 sticks are reported, but on the top it says total memory is 24GB: http://imgur.com/mAktGxT

Comment: Perhaps this is a hardware error? I would try removing individual sticks & re-running something like memtest to see if that 24 GiB out of four sticks total ever changes.

Comment: @Landak Yep, that's what I was trying to avoid, but I guess I'll have to do that and see how it goes. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Alright, it does look like one of the sticks just doesn't work, so I'll contact the supplier and get that sorted out. Thanks for your help everybody!